# CakePHP plugins and database setup

Tags: database, cakephp, plugins

With CakePHP you can create plugins that seem to work "semi-independently".

I would like to know if there is any way to create a setup file/class for database schema on which plugin models will be mapped.

Comment: what do you want to be able to configure in that file / class? The DB connection?

Comment: No, I would like to run (only if necesary) the "CREATE TABLE" scripts, so the plugin is "plug and play", and the preliminary manual db update is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will want to use the Cake shell schema, or make use of the CakeDC/Migrations plugin.

Both will allow you to generate a schema file which can then be run with 'cake schema run' to create tables for your plugin.

Ref, `cake schema generate`
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html

Ref, `cake migrations.migration generate`
https://github.com/cakedc/migrations